# generating email address images or something which can't be easily scraped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a better Text-to-image solution for my Rails project to replace my current method which is generating a png using ImageMagick every time a new record is created or updated.

I want to prevent a mass scraping of data and abuse of email addresses provided.  I'm wondering if there is an API to generate the text or use of javascript, or SVG, etc. Anything short of Flash.

I'm looking for a better solution than my current method:

```
  def create_new_email_image

    if email_changed?

      path_to_images = '/images/emails'

      puts "Connecting to AWS..."
      config = YAML.load(File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3_credentials.yml"))[RAILS_ENV]
      AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
        :access_key_id     => config['access_key_id'],
        :secret_access_key => config['secret_access_key']
      )

      puts "Finding S3 bucket..."
      begin
        bucket = AWS::S3::Bucket.find config['bucket_name']
      rescue AWS::S3::NoSuchBucket
        AWS::S3::Bucket.create config['bucket_name']
        bucket = AWS::S3::Bucket.find config['bucket_name']
      end

      images_path = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/"
      file_name = "#{id}.png"
      #file_name = "5056.png"
      file_path = images_path + "/"+ file_name

      File.delete file_path if File.exists? file_path

      img = Magick::Image.new(400, 22) { self.background_color = 'transparent' }
      img.format = 'PNG'

      text = Magick::Draw.new
      text.annotate(img, 0, 0, 1, 0, "#{email}") {
          self.gravity = Magick::WestGravity
          self.pointsize = 18
          self.fill = '#000000'
          self.kerning = -1
          self.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
          }

      img.write file_path

      if AWS::S3::S3Object.exists? file_name, bucket.name + path_to_images
        puts "file exists (deleting)"
        AWS::S3::S3Object.delete file_name, bucket.name + path_to_images, :force => true
      end

      AWS::S3::S3Object.store file_name, 
         File.open(file_path), 
         bucket.name + path_to_images, 
         :content_type => 'image/png',
         :access => :public_read,
         :reload => true

      `rm #{file_path}`
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why do you want to replace your current working solution?

Comment: My current solution seemed a tad overkill & i thought maybe there'd be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides a [mail_to helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to).

```
mail_to "me@domain.com"
# => <a href="mailto:me@domain.com">me@domain.com</a>

mail_to "me@domain.com", "My email", :encode => "javascript"
# => <script type="text/javascript">eval(decodeURIComponent('%64%6f%63...%27%29%3b'))</script>

mail_to "me@domain.com", "My email", :encode => "hex"
# => <a href="mailto:%6d%65@%64%6f%6d%61%69%6e.%63%6f%6d">My email</a>

mail_to "me@domain.com", nil, :replace_at => "_at_", :replace_dot => "_dot_", :class => "email"
# => <a href="mailto:me@domain.com" class="email">me_at_domain_dot_com</a>

mail_to "me@domain.com", "My email", :cc => "ccaddress@domain.com",
         :subject => "This is an example email"
# => <a href="mailto:me@domain.com?cc=ccaddress@domain.com&subject=This%20is%20an%20example%20email">My email</a>
```

The `:encode => "hex"` or `:encode => "javascript"` options are what you are looking for.

Comment: I've always used various spins on Javascript encoding of the email address. Using Rail's helpers to alternate randomly through its different ways of obfuscating the addresses would be a good way of foiling scraping attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Here is my solution:

```
def text_to_image(text,options={})
    return if text.blank?
    filename=get_text_file_path(text)
    unless File.exists?(filename)
      gc = Magick::Draw.new
      gc.fill = options[:color] unless options[:color].blank?
      gc.pointsize options[:size] unless options[:size].blank?
      gc.font=options[:font] unless options[:font].blank?
      gc.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
      gc.text(0,0, text)
      metrics=gc.get_type_metrics(text)
      image = Magick::Image.new(metrics.width, metrics.height){
        self.background_color = 'transparent'
        }
      gc.draw(image)
      image.write(filename)
    end
  end
```

I use `after_save` callback to update graphic cache of email attribute.